# Where is ispell private dictionary located on Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, ispell, spell-checking

My Spacemacs help ispell-personal-dictionary says:

```
ispell-personal-dictionary is a variable defined in ‘ispell.el’.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
File name of your personal spelling dictionary, or nil.
If nil, the default personal dictionary, ("~/.ispell_DICTNAME" for ispell or
"~/.aspell.LANG.pws" for Aspell) is used, where DICTNAME is the name of your
default dictionary and LANG the two letter language code.
```

But there is no "~/.ispell_DICTNAME" or "~/.aspell_DICTNAME" on my system:

```
$ ls -A .isp*
ls: cannot access '.isp*': No such file or directory
$ ls -A .asp*
ls: cannot access '.asp*': No such file or directory
```

ispell is working and I accidentaly added a misspelled word to it.
Now I want to remove the entry from my ispell private dictionary.

How to find the ispell private dictionary location?

System Info :computer:

- OS: gnu/linux
- Emacs: 25.3.1
- Spacemacs: 0.200.10
- Spacemacs branch: master (rev. 4bb4cb46)
- Graphic display: t
- Distribution: spacemacs
- Editing style: vim
- Completion: ivy
- Layers:
  `elisp
  (c-c++ emacs-lisp evil-snipe git ivy org shell spell-checking)`
- System configuration features: XPM JPEG TIFF GIF PNG RSVG IMAGEMAGICK SOUND DBUS GCONF GSETTINGS NOTIFY ACL LIBSELINUX GNUTLS LIBXML2 FREETYPE M17N_FLT LIBOTF XFT ZLIB TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS GTK3 X11 MODULES XWIDGETS

**UPDATE 1:**

aspell doesn't seem to be on my system:

```
$ aspell -h
bash: aspell: command not found.
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I found aspell, but it's unresponsive:

```
$ pwd
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions
$ ls aspell
aspell
$ aspell --lang=en dump config
bash: aspell: command not found...
Install package 'aspell' to provide command 'aspell'? [N/y] n
$ aspell -h
bash: aspell: command not found.
$ sudo ./aspell -h
sudo: ./aspell: command not found
```

**UPDATE 3:**

To uninstall aspell, I commented spell-checking in ~/.spacemacs, and restarted Emacs.

Then I reinstalled as described in https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/+checkers/spell-checking#install and restarted Emacs again.
Emacs opening page said:

```
Found 3 new package(s) to install...
--> refreshing package archive: melpa-stable... [2/2]
--> installing package: flyspell-correct-ivy@spell-checking... [3/3]
```

Still have same result with absolute path:

```
$ sudo /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/aspell -h
sudo: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/aspell: command not found
```

**UPDATE 4:**

From Spacemacs help - SPC SPC h d v ispell-program-name:

```
ispell-program-name is a variable defined in ‘ispell.el’.
Its value is "/usr/bin/hunspell"
```

From command line:

```
$ hunspell -v
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.2.06 (but really Hunspell 1.5.4)
$ hunspell -h
```

I googled: emacs private dictionary location

Still not finding the location of my private dictionary.

Comment: This is not a spacemacs thing-a-majig.  It is an `aspell` configuration setting, which can be changed with `aspell.conf`.  To dump the current configuration, open the terminal and type:  `aspell --lang=en dump config` or use the absolute path if so desired:  `/path/to/aspell --lang=en dump config`.  Dumping the configuration will tell you where the `aspell.conf` needs to go, and there are several threads on Google with sample settings.

Comment: @lawlist, aspell doesn't seem to be on my system (see UPDATE 1 at end of question).

Comment: If you have searched your hard drive and cannot locate `aspell`, then you will need to install it if that is the utility you wish to use in conjunction with `flyspell` / `ispell` in Emacs.  Emacs does not come with the utility known as `aspell`.  Be aware that some people may prefer `hunspell` over `aspell` ...  See this helpful blog:  http://blog.binchen.org/posts/what-s-the-best-spell-check-set-up-in-emacs.html  See also this related thread for users of OSX:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022015/emacs-on-mac-os-x-how-to-get-spell-check-to-work/21749058

Comment: @lawlist, I found aspell but it's unresponsive (see UPDATE 2 at end of question).

Comment: It appears as though you may need to learn, by Googling and reading, how to add a program to your `$PATH` and depending upon the platform that Emacs is being used, it will be necessary to set the `$PATH` within Emacs also (e.g., Emacs for OSX does not automatically use the system `$PATH`).  If you do not wish to play around with setting the `$PATH` for certain utilities, you can always use the absolute path.  See the first comment above of what this looks like.  If `aspell` is broken somehow, then you may need to reinstall it -- using the absolute path should be sufficient if it is working.

Comment: As to your third edit/update to the original question, the page you linked to states in relevant part:  "*It will give priority to `aspell` **if** it is installed on your system.*"  Installation of Spacemacs does *not* install `aspell`, which is a separate utility/program that needs to be installed *by some other method* if it does not already exist on the hard drive.  The method for installing `aspell` differs depending upon the operating system and the user's preferred methods for installing a utility of that nature.  Google your operating system and how to install `aspell` ...

Comment: @lawlist,
My spell checker is working, although it may not be aspell.
How to find out what spell checker my Spacemacs is using?
Thanks for your patients.

Comment: I don't use Spacemacs (about 100 miscellaneous packages and various configurations), but you could try seeing what the variable `ispell-program-name` is set to; e.g., type `M-x describe-variable RET ispell-program-name RET` or the shortcut `C-h v` ....

Answer (score 1):

First, look at the variable `ispell-personal-dictionary`.  If itʼs set, thatʼs your answer.

Next, look at the variable `ispell-program-name`.  This is the spell-checking backend that Emacs is currently using, and each backend will store your private dictionary in a different place:

- Aspell: `~/.aspell.??.pws`
- Enchant: `~/.config/enchant/*.dic`
- Hunspell: `~/.hunspell_*`

In each case, the exact file used will vary based on the language youʼre using.

Answer (score 0):

I never found the Emacs private dictionary on Debian 9.
But when I installed Fedora 28, it was easily found at ~/.hunspell_en_US

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu system, it's located at `~/.aspell.en.pws`